# A question about associated operator on continuous functions space equiped with L2 norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-measure

$$\text{For M a connected compact manifold, T is in }C^{1+\nu}(M,M) \text{ with } \nu\in(0,1),\\ \text{i.e. DT is some Hölder continuous function with Hölder exponent }\\ \text{, Denote m as the Lebesgue measure on M and suppose M has finite Lebesgue measure.}$$

$$\text{For the associated operator defined on the L2 normed vector space}\\
U:(C^0(M, \mathbb{R}),\lVert  \rVert_2)\rightarrow (C^0(M,\mathbb{R}),\lVert  \rVert_2):$$

$$U(f)=f\circ T$$,
$$\text{Can we prove U is a bounded operator due to DT is Hölder continuous?}$$
(I guess it can be a radon nikodym derivative)

Comment: $$\text{Indeed for } d\mu=DTdm,\text{so for the } L_2(\mu) \text{ norm} ||U(f)||^2=(||f||^{\mu}_{2})^2\le ||f||_{2}^{2}||DT||_{2}^{2}$$ by cauchy schwartz

Comment: Please note it's "Hölder", not "holder", and "(Hermann) Schwarz", not "(Laurent) Schwartz"

Comment: Thank you vm, I fixed the holder to be Hölder. And Thank you for letting me know the famous Inequality was named after [Hermann Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz)